# Unable to download PKpass from server

Tags: swift4, wallet, passkit, apple-wallet, pkpass

I've been trying several links to download pkpass from server but whenever i download it it shows me the size of file "0 kb", due to this i cannot convert it to pkpass data.
is there any other way for dynamic pkpass ?
or some other way to download and load it to wallet ?

is it doing because pkpass contain certificates and private information thats why it's not downloading ?

I cannot find any way to integrate dynamic pkpass in app using swift 4.2 or above.

the links I've been using but none of it works

-> [Downloading PKPass in an iOS custom app from my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277120/downloading-pkpass-in-an-ios-custom-app-from-my-server)

-> [Unable to add Pass to Apple Wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927087/unable-to-add-pass-to-apple-wallet/57575585#57575585)

-> [open .pkpass file from Wallet using share extension iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007659/open-pkpass-file-from-wallet-using-share-extension-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got a solution to get pkpass from server by:
-> simply get base64 string from api response
-> convert that base64 to to Data like this below

```
private func convertBase64ToData (base64Str:String) -> Void {
    let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64Str, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    openPkPassDataFile(passData: data!)
}
```

-> then convert Data to PKPass like this below

```
private func openPkPassDataFile(passData:Data) -> Void{
    let pass = try? PKPass(data: passData)
    
    let passLibrary = PKPassLibrary()
    if passLibrary.containsPass(pass!) {
        print("This pass already added in wallet. Thanks!")
    } else {
        let pkvc = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: pass!)
        pkvc!.delegate = self
        self.present(pkvc!, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
        })
    }
}
```

Note: add **import PassKit** and **PKAddPassesViewControllerDelegate** in your controller.